# Copying and Pasting data into a specific row and column

Tags: vba

I have a spreadsheet that calculates scores for individuals for a certain month. I currently have a macro that copies the current score into a table based on the person's name. I would like to be able track the scores over multiple months in a table. For example, Imagine my scorecard gave John a score of 85 in May. I would want the macro to put Johns score in the table as shown below.

```
Name   Jan  Feb  Mar  April  May  June
Jim
James
John                         85
Jack
```

I tried working it out using the macro I have that does this for one dimension (i.e. puts the current score next to the name) but didn't have any luck. The non-functioning code is below:

```
Private Sub MonthScore()

Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

row = 2

column = 2

Do While (Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, column).Value <> "")
    If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row).Value = Sheets("Scorecard").Range("B2").Value _
     And Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, column).Value = Sheets("Scorecard").Range("J2") Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, column).Value = Sheets("Scorecard").Range("H15").Value
    End If
row = row + 1
column = column + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Any help with getting this code to work (or any set of code that will make this work) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There seem to be 3 sheets involved here? ("Sheet2", "Scorecard" and `Sheet7`)  Can you confirm/fix ?

Comment: change `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, column).Value = Sheets("Scorecard").Range(H15).Value`  to `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, column).Value = Sheets("Scorecard").Range("H15").Value`

Comment: There should only be 2 sheets, `Sheet7` should be "Sheet2". I fixed it in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Application.Match()` to locate the values in the Name and Month ranges:

```
Sub MonthScore()

    Dim mR, mC
    Dim shtSC, sht2

    Set shtSC = Sheets("Scorecard")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    mR = Application.Match(shtSC.Range("B2").Value, sht2.Columns(1), 0)
    If Not IsError(mR) Then

        mC = Application.Match(shtSC.Range("J2").Value, sht2.Rows(1), 0)

        If Not IsError(mC) Then
            sht2.Cells(mR, mC).Value = shtSC.Range("H15").Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```